# Image from Webcam

Tags: image, webcam

How can I capture the image from webcam with a program in C/C++ and then process the image and possibility transmit it over ethernet.

Has any way to create it in Windows and Linux easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the OpenCV library to capture the images: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture

When using OpenCV video capture on Windows, you will need to register the DirectShow filters. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/faq#Windows.2BAK4OSrelatedQs.3A

Windows has an out-dated API for capturing video called Video for Windows (VfW) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_for_Windows